# Specs satisfying firebase_analytics from .symlinks/plugins/firebase_analytics/ios dependency were found, but required higher minimum deployment target

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, cocoapods, firebase-analytics

I've just tried to build my flutter application via CodeMagic using VNC Viewer and SSH with no luck.

I have tried to run "pod install" with result:

```
Analyzing dependencies
firebase_analytics: Using Firebase SDK version '8.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '8.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '8.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "firebase_analytics":
  In Podfile:
    firebase_analytics (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_analytics/ios`)

Specs satisfying the `firebase_analytics (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_analytics/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `9.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
```

I have also tried to delete the Podfile.lock and pod install. with similar results. I have also tried to run pod repo update and then pod update with similar results as above.

I have also tried to manually change my Podfile iOS version to 10 without luck.

I've tried various combinations of these commands:

```
flutter clean
flutter build ios

pod install
pod update
pod repo update
pod install --repo-update
```

Please any responses will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I initially thought I had tried it with 12 but turns out I must not have. 12 and I was able to solve this problem but my advice to anyone is avoid doing this set up via CodeMagic, it's not fun!

Comment: Plz be more specific about what you mean by "tried with 12"!... What exactly did you do with your 12?

Comment: I tried this with IOS version 12, sorry, I thought this would be obvious

Comment: Ok, that explains the "12" bit. Only the "tried" bit remaining. :) What exactly did you do? You say you "were able to solve this problem"... or do you mean that the problem didn't even occur on iOS 12?

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply and my brain is now likely forgetting this but I believe it did not occur on 12